# What tricks do you use to avoid damaging cables when adjusting the gears?

Tags: gears, cable

I was trying to adjust gears, and being my first time, I ended up damaging the cable. I mean that I "smashed" it, the threads became apart, and it was dangerous to deal with it. I replaced the cable, but I would like to avoid the problem in the future. Is there any trick, apart from being careful? I'm thinking something like coating the cable with a bit of glue. Is it ok?

Comment: By adjusting do you mean shifting or performing maintenance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put the cable in, find a length that's 'approximate enough', and crimp the cable end onto the cable before I clamp it into the derailleur. This will prevent the end from fraying, like you say, and becoming difficult to deal with. It will get flattened under the derailleur clamp, but this can't be avoided.

If you don't crimp the end in first (or leaving it long is another way, but it doesn't always work), then you will have to deal with the frayed cable and sometimes need to wind it back together to get it into the cable end.

Comment: Yes, the derailleur clamp was my problem. The cable got flattened as you say. I adjusted it many times until I finally understood how to tune to rear derailleur. If I glue in advance the section that is going to be clamped, would it help?

Comment: @Javier -- What do you mean by "glue"?

Comment: Glue works, just a drop on the end to bind the wires.

Comment: I suppose some superglue might help initially, but once it's clamped once there it'll break the glue's bonds with the wires. I've never concerned myself with the flattened cable section - it doesn't fray the cable when it's clamped beforehand.

Comment: some derailleur clamps have a little notch through which the cable can pass that minimizes the amount of squishing. I don't know if yours is made like that but if it is be sure to line it up in the notch.

Comment: There are apropriate cable ends for that purpose, but you have other alternatives as a last resort (they are not neat but they will do in a hurry): I have used thin cooper wire winded at cable end in a tight spiral (forming like a bolt). You can also use the kind of soldering metal (lead or tin?) that is used for electronics. I Have also used a small ball of epoxy glue, I let it dry a little and stick it into the cable end while it is a moldeable putty.

Comment: I noticed the notch. That will help. @Jahaziel: Could you post a link where those cable ends are described? Should I buy the entire cable with such end? And just to be clear, I'm not talking about the cap for the very end of the cable. That I installed without problem

Comment: They are called "inner cable caps". I was unable to find a textual description, they are made of aluminum, you snap them into the cable end and then use a crimper to make them tight against cable. Here are some pictures: http://www.comparestoreprices.co.uk/images/tr/transfil-pack-of-100-anti-fray-inner-cable-end-caps.jpg, http://www.huskybicycles.com/Merchant2/graphics/00000002/311-186.jpg

Comment: Are those the ones that I mentioned before? They seem to be for the very end of the cable. I installed one already. What I want is one that goes where the clamp is going to bite the cable, if it exists.

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing, nor ever found it necessary or desirable. If it's that important, solder it together with some silver solder before you crimp it; but this seems unnecessary to the extreme.

Comment: If you frayed the cable even with the cable ends installed, then you either routed the cable badly or tightened it way too much, but more likely the first. The "notch" mentioned is normally a groove, a sort of line that passes close to the holding bolt hole, and the auxiliary clamp (a small metallic piece that the bolt holds) also has one and should be aligned with the other. Are you using it? It is very rare to install a cable with the bolt alone, the little clamp is must.